# jQuery array() with select on change

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to minimize my code by putting it into an array but nothing happens. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Here's the code

```
<html>
    <head>

    <title>test</title>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var phpfile = new Object();
        phpfile["testselect"] = "zoomchange.php";


        var elementID = new Object();
        elementID["testselect"] = "#testdiv";

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("select").change(function() {
              $.post(
                phpfile[$(this).id()],
                $(this).serialize(),
                function(data) {
                  $(elementID[$(this).id()]).html(data)
                }
              );

            });

        });

    </script>   

    </head>

    <body>


    <select id="testselect">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <div id="testdiv"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

here is the zoomchange.php:

```
<?PHP echo $_REQUEST['testselect'] ; ?>
```

Comment: Any kind of errors from Firebug/Dev tools?

Comment: first you need to choose one doctype and delete comment and don't try to minimize your code, but make it clear and readable.

Comment: validate  your java script code in `jslint.com`

Answer (score 2):

Your initializers shouldn't look like this:

```
var phpfile = new Array();
phpfile["testselect"] = "zoomchange.php";

var elementID = new Array();
elementID["testselect"] = "#testdiv";
```

A JavaScript Array is indexed by numbers, not strings. You want simple object literals:

```
var phpfile   = { testselect: 'zoomchange.php' };
var elementED = { testselect: '#testdiv'       };
```

Then, your POST callback is confused:

```
function(data) {
    $(elementID[$(this).id()]).html(data)
}
```

`this` isn't what you think it is when that function is called. You want something more like this:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var that = this;
    $.post(
        phpfile[that.id],
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(data) {
            $(elementID[that.id]).html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do `new Object()` instead of `new Array()`.
**Edit**: There are other mistakes, your js code should be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var phpfile = {};
        phpfile["testselect"] = "zoomchange.php";

        var elementID = {};
        elementID["testselect"] = "#testdiv";

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("select").change(function() {
              var $select = $(this);
              $.post(
                phpfile[$select.attr("id")],
                $select.serialize(),
                function(data) {
                  $(elementID[$select.attr("id")]).html(data)
                }
              );

            });
       });
</script>
```

Comment: @ariel, It's a bad practice to store hashtables in javascript arrays, they must be in objects

Comment: cool.. didn't knew that. but that wasn't the error, probably was the reference to 'this' inside the ajax callback

Comment: ok the obove script updated the div with the random text i but on the bottom of the page...  but the select is not getting submitted

Comment: with Edgar Villegas Alvarado script i checked firebug and there is no post data

Answer (score 0):

This

```
function(data)
{
  $(elementID[$(this).id()]).html(data);
}
```

instead of this

```
function(data)
{
  $(elementID[$(this).id()]).html(data)
}
```

Is this the error ?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't require semicolon statement terminators (even though you really should use them).

Comment: in javascript a semicolon before } is optional